# RewriteRule Image from php file to another php script

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/) and I have no problem using it with normal linked images that end in `.jpg, .png, .gif` but when I use a filesystem that a php file grabs a unextensioned file from a directory and uses header `Content-Disposition: inline` to display the image, the htaccess does not properly run it through the php file.

Here is the Rewrite rule that works for normal linked images:

```
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php [NC,L]
```

Here is an example of a image link that needs to be run through `adaptive-images.php`:

```
http://localhost/projects/file-system/getmedia.php?id=2&slug=35dq
```

**How do I write another rewrite rule that will take care of those images?** I am currently using this rule but it just makes broken images (I have tried some other rules but no difference):

```
RewriteRule ^getmedia.php$ adaptive-images.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: have you tried RewriteRule ^projects/file-system/getmedia.php adaptive-images.php [NC, L]

Comment: @sanj That does not work at all. Gives a 500 internal error (even moving the $).

Comment: any way, you need to set full url into rule, i don't know how your apache configured, you can try RewriteRule /projects/file-system/getmedia.php google.com [R] to check it works or not.

Comment: Also, you might want to add the `QSA` tag so that the queries sent to `getmedia.php` also get sent to `adaptive-images.php`.

Comment: @MikeAnthony No Change. Not sure I need it because the normal adaptive images rule doesn't need it.

Comment: @MLM: I see - wasn't aware that this is a distribution. Just looked into how it works. I think it's because it's actually looking for an image file... Can't be sure though, would need to examine the source.

Comment: @MikeAnthony Ye, I figured out yesterday that it is an issue with using a php file to feed the images instead of the htaccess although I am using a different rules. I am working on making some changes to the script to accommodate this type of file delivery/system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my htaccess rule was maybe at fault, the adaptive images php script does not accommodate php fed images natively.

**The htaccess rule I used was:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)noadaptive=(true)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^getmedia\.php.*$ adaptive-images.php [NC,L]
```

This allows me to send all the images generated by `getmedia.php` to be sent into `adaptive-images.php` and if it has `noadaptive=true` as a get parameter then it does not utilize the script so I can get full sized images again.

**Here is the modified `adaptive-images.php`**

```
<?php

//sendErrorImage("there is a problem");

/* PROJECT INFO --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Version:   1.5.2
   Changelog: http://adaptive-images.com/changelog.txt

   Homepage:  http://adaptive-images.com
   GitHub:    https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images
   Twitter:   @responsiveimg

   LEGAL:
   Adaptive Images by Matt Wilcox is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.

/* CONFIG ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* MODIFICATIONS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mods by:        MLM from VisualPulse.net
    Description:    Added compatibility for php fed images.
                    Intended for use with a ambiguous file system that serve the files through a php file

    NOTE: These are unofficial modifications I made up to get this wonderful script to work with my file system.
*/


$resolutions = array(1382, 992, 768, 480); // the resolution break-points to use (screen widths, in pixels)
$cache_path = "ai-cache"; // where to store the generated re-sized images. Specify from your document root!
$jpg_quality = 100; // the quality of any generated JPGs on a scale of 0 to 100
$sharpen = TRUE; // Shrinking images can blur details, perform a sharpen on re-scaled images?
$watch_cache = TRUE; // check that the adapted image isn't stale (ensures updated source images are re-cached)
$browser_cache = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // How long the BROWSER cache should last (seconds, minutes, hours, days. 7days by default)

/* END CONFIG ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------ Don't edit anything after this line unless you know what you're doing -------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* get all of the required data from the HTTP request */
$document_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$requested_uri = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), PHP_URL_PATH);
$requested_uri_more_stuff = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$requested_file = basename($requested_uri);
//$source_file = $document_root . $requested_uri;

file_put_contents('array.txt', var_export($requested_uri_more_stuff, TRUE));

if(pathinfo($requested_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php')
    $source_file = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $requested_uri. ((!empty($requested_uri_more_stuff['query']) ? ('?' . $requested_uri_more_stuff['query']) : '') . (((parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY) == NULL) ? '?' : '&') . 'noadaptive=true'));
else
    $source_file = $document_root . $requested_uri;

$resolution = FALSE;

//sendErrorImage(pathinfo($requested_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
//sendErrorImage($source_file);


/* Mobile detection 
   NOTE: only used in the event a cookie isn't available. */
function is_mobile()
{
    $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    return strpos($userAgent, 'mobile');
}

/* Does the UA string indicate this is a mobile? */
if (!is_mobile()) {
    $is_mobile = FALSE;
} else {
    $is_mobile = TRUE;
}

// does the $cache_path directory exist already?
if (!is_dir("$document_root/$cache_path")) { // no
    if (!mkdir("$document_root/$cache_path", 0755, true)) { // so make it
        if (!is_dir("$document_root/$cache_path")) { // check again to protect against race conditions
            // uh-oh, failed to make that directory
            sendErrorImage("Failed to create cache directory at: $document_root/$cache_path");
        }
    }
}

/* helper function: Send headers and returns an image. */
function sendImage($filename, $browser_cache)
{
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($extension, array('png', 'gif', 'jpeg'))) {
        header("Content-Type: image/" . $extension);
    } else {
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    }
    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=" . $browser_cache);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $browser_cache) . ' GMT');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit();
}

/* helper function: Create and send an image with an error message. */
function sendErrorImage($message)
{
    /* get all of the required data from the HTTP request */
    $document_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $requested_uri = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), PHP_URL_PATH);
    $requested_file = basename($requested_uri);
    $source_file = $document_root . $requested_uri;

    if (!is_mobile()) {
        $is_mobile = "FALSE";
    } else {
        $is_mobile = "TRUE";
    }

    $im = ImageCreateTrueColor(800, 300);
    $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    $message_color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 91, 112, 233);

    ImageString($im, 5, 5, 5, "Adaptive Images encountered a problem:", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 25, $message, $message_color);

    ImageString($im, 5, 5, 85, "Potentially useful information:", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 105, "DOCUMENT ROOT IS: $document_root", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 125, "REQUESTED URI WAS: $requested_uri", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 145, "REQUESTED FILE WAS: $requested_file", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 165, "SOURCE FILE IS: $source_file", $text_color);
    ImageString($im, 3, 5, 185, "DEVICE IS MOBILE? $is_mobile", $text_color);
    //ImageString($im, 3, 5, 205, "Resolution: $resolution", $text_color); // Doesn't work

    header("Cache-Control: no-store");
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() - 1000) . ' GMT');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    ImageJpeg($im);
    ImageDestroy($im);
    exit();
}

/* sharpen images function */
function findSharp($intOrig, $intFinal)
{
    $intFinal = $intFinal * (750.0 / $intOrig);
    $intA = 52;
    $intB = -0.27810650887573124;
    $intC = .00047337278106508946;
    $intRes = $intA + $intB * $intFinal + $intC * $intFinal * $intFinal;
    return max(round($intRes), 0);
}

/* refreshes the cached image if it's outdated */
function refreshCache($source_file, $cache_file, $resolution)
{
    if (file_exists($cache_file)) {
        // not modified
        if (filemtime($cache_file) >= filemtime($source_file)) {
            return $cache_file;
        }

        // modified, clear it
        unlink($cache_file);
    }
    return generateImage($source_file, $cache_file, $resolution);
}

/* generates the given cache file for the given source file with the given resolution */
function generateImage($source_file, $cache_file, $resolution)
{
    global $sharpen, $jpg_quality;



    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($source_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check the image dimensions
    $dimensions = getimagesize($source_file);
    $width = $dimensions[0];
    $height = $dimensions[1];

    //sendErrorImage($width . ' ' . $resolution);
    // Do we need to downscale the image?
    if ($width <= $resolution) { // no, because the width of the source image is already less than the client width
        return $source_file;
    }


    // We need to resize the source image to the width of the resolution breakpoint we're working with
    $ratio = $height / $width;
    $new_width = $resolution;
    $new_height = ceil($new_width * $ratio);
    $dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width, $new_height); // re-sized image

    switch ($extension) {
        case 'png':
            $src = @imagecreatefrompng($source_file); // original image
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src = @imagecreatefromgif($source_file); // original image
            break;
        default:

            //imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($source_file));
            $src = @imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file); // original image
            ImageInterlace($dst, true); // Enable interlancing (progressive JPG, smaller size file)
            break;
    }

    if ($extension == 'png') {
        imagealphablending($dst, false);
        imagesavealpha($dst, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($dst, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);
    }

    ImageCopyResampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height); // do the resize in memory
    ImageDestroy($src);

    // sharpen the image?
    // NOTE: requires PHP compiled with the bundled version of GD (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php)
    if ($sharpen == TRUE && function_exists('imageconvolution')) {
        $intSharpness = findSharp($width, $new_width);
        $arrMatrix = array(
            array(-1, -2, -1),
            array(-2, $intSharpness + 12, -2),
            array(-1, -2, -1)
        );
        imageconvolution($dst, $arrMatrix, $intSharpness, 0);
    }

    $cache_dir = dirname($cache_file);

    //sendErrorImage($cache_dir);

    // does the directory exist already?
    if (!is_dir($cache_dir)) {
        if (!mkdir($cache_dir, 0755, true)) {
            // check again if it really doesn't exist to protect against race conditions
            if (!is_dir($cache_dir)) {
                // uh-oh, failed to make that directory
                ImageDestroy($dst);
                sendErrorImage("Failed to create cache directory: $cache_dir");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!is_writable($cache_dir)) {
        sendErrorImage("The cache directory is not writable: $cache_dir");
    }

    // save the new file in the appropriate path, and send a version to the browser
    switch ($extension) {
        case 'png':
            $gotSaved = ImagePng($dst, $cache_file);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $gotSaved = ImageGif($dst, $cache_file);
            break;
        default:
            $gotSaved = ImageJpeg($dst, $cache_file, $jpg_quality);
            break;
    }
    ImageDestroy($dst);

    if (!$gotSaved && !file_exists($cache_file)) {
        sendErrorImage("Failed to create image: $cache_file");
    }

    return $cache_file;
}



//sendErrorImage($source_file);
// check if the file exists at all
if(pathinfo($requested_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php')
{
    if (!file_exists($source_file)) {
        //sendErrorImage('404 ' . $source_file);
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        exit();
    }
}
else if(pathinfo($requested_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == php)
{

}

/* check that PHP has the GD library available to use for image re-sizing */
if (!extension_loaded('gd')) { // it's not loaded
    if (!function_exists('dl') || !dl('gd.so')) { // and we can't load it either
        // no GD available, so deliver the image straight up
        trigger_error('You must enable the GD extension to make use of Adaptive Images', E_USER_WARNING);
        sendImage($source_file, $browser_cache);
    }
}

/* Check to see if a valid cookie exists */
if (isset($_COOKIE['resolution'])) {
    $cookie_value = $_COOKIE['resolution'];

    // does the cookie look valid? [whole number, comma, potential floating number]
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+[,]*[0-9\.]+$/", "$cookie_value")) { // no it doesn't look valid
        setcookie("resolution", "$cookie_value", time() - 100); // delete the mangled cookie
    } else { // the cookie is valid, do stuff with it
        $cookie_data = explode(",", $_COOKIE['resolution']);
        $client_width = (int)$cookie_data[0]; // the base resolution (CSS pixels)
        $total_width = $client_width;
        $pixel_density = 1; // set a default, used for non-retina style JS snippet
        if (@$cookie_data[1]) { // the device's pixel density factor (physical pixels per CSS pixel)
            $pixel_density = $cookie_data[1];
        }

        rsort($resolutions); // make sure the supplied break-points are in reverse size order
        $resolution = $resolutions[0]; // by default use the largest supported break-point

        // if pixel density is not 1, then we need to be smart about adapting and fitting into the defined breakpoints
        if ($pixel_density != 1) {


            $total_width = $client_width * $pixel_density; // required physical pixel width of the image

            // the required image width is bigger than any existing value in $resolutions
            if ($total_width > $resolutions[0]) {
                // firstly, fit the CSS size into a break point ignoring the multiplier
                foreach ($resolutions as $break_point) { // filter down
                    if ($total_width <= $break_point) {
                        $resolution = $break_point;
                    }
                }
                // now apply the multiplier
                $resolution = $resolution * $pixel_density;
            } // the required image fits into the existing breakpoints in $resolutions
            else {
                foreach ($resolutions as $break_point) { // filter down
                    if ($total_width <= $break_point) {
                        $resolution = $break_point;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // pixel density is 1, just fit it into one of the breakpoints
            foreach ($resolutions as $break_point) { // filter down
                if ($total_width <= $break_point) {
                    $resolution = $break_point;
                }
            }
            //sendErrorImage($client_width . " " . $resolution . " " . $pixel_density . " | " . $total_width);
        }
    }
}

/* No resolution was found (no cookie or invalid cookie) */
if (!$resolution) {
    // We send the lowest resolution for mobile-first approach, and highest otherwise
    $resolution = $is_mobile ? min($resolutions) : max($resolutions);
}


/* if the requested URL starts with a slash, remove the slash */
if (substr($requested_uri, 0, 1) == "/") {
    $requested_uri = substr($requested_uri, 1);
}

/* whew might the cache file be? */
if(pathinfo($requested_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php')
{
    $getstring = '';
    foreach($_GET as $key => $item)
    {
        $getstring .= $key . '~' . $item . '^';
    }

    $fileinfophp = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    //sendErrorImage($getstring);
    $cache_file = $document_root . "/$cache_path/$resolution/" . 'php/' . $fileinfophp['filename'] . '%' . $getstring;
}
else
    $cache_file = $document_root . "/$cache_path/$resolution/" . $requested_uri;

/* Use the resolution value as a path variable and check to see if an image of the same name exists at that path */
if (file_exists($cache_file)) { // it exists cached at that size
    if ($watch_cache) { // if cache watching is enabled, compare cache and source modified dates to ensure the cache isn't stale
        $cache_file = refreshCache($source_file, $cache_file, $resolution);
    }

    sendImage($cache_file, $browser_cache);
}

//sendErrorImage('gen');
/* It exists as a source file, and it doesn't exist cached - lets make one: */
$file = generateImage($source_file, $cache_file, $resolution);
//file_put_contents('image.jpg', $file);
sendImage($file, $browser_cache);
```